# System requirements for Cometd/Bayeux Usage on Android

Tags: java, android, jetty, cometd, bayeux

I'm trying to implement a Cometd/Bayeux server on Android using iJetty.  The Jetty implementation itself works just fine serving static pages along with servlets.  I am trying to up the ante a bit and create a Bayeux application on the phone but I'm having some trouble.  I can hit the page that has the dojo cometd scripts on it, but I am unable to subscribe to the channel.  When I view firebug/chome developer tools, I see a series of posts/gets that last a couple of milliseconds (~14).  However, when I run a cometd application on a normal machine, the posts/gets last several seconds (~14 seconds) before timing out and reopening the connection.  This second scenario makes sense to me with my understanding of how continuation in HTTP works.  So I'm thinking that something is not allowing those connections to hang open and prematurely returning a value and consequently closing the connection.  I would post my source but I'm not sure what to post short of posting everything...(it is open source though so if you want to have a look it's at http://webtext-android.googlecode.com).

So my question is, does anybody think that there could be some underlying limitation imposed by the Android system that is preventing these servlets from working? Are there assumptions that are made by the Jetty Bayeux implementation with regards to the underlying system? Or is it more likely that somehow I have a bad implementation of the ContinuationCometdServelt?  I should note that all of the posts/gets from the client return 200 OK messages so I'm not inclined to think that the Android system is simply terminating the connection.

I know this is a bit off the wall and I'm definitely trying to do something a bit out of the ordinary but any suggestions or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1 because running Jetty on an Android device is nerdy : )

Comment: try to catch me white and nerdy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anybody discovers this and has similar problems (this applies to all cometd implementations regardless of host), I discovered that the issue was with using the Google js library.  For some reason, the dojo scripts I was loading from Google (1.4) didn't have a valid implementation of cometd.  I switched my dojo script to the one that was used by the jetty-1.6.23 example and it works perfectly.